# Dlib rotating image on Z axis

Tags: c++, c++11, image-processing, dlib

I'm trying to generate some images by rotating on Z axis using dlib.
I have found the mothod `point_transform_affine3d rotate_around_z(double angle)` but I don't understand how to use it.

My starting point is an `array2d<unsigned char> image` loaded from a JPG file and I need to rotate this image from -10 to +10 degrees.

For example, to rotate over X and Y axis using an array of images I used this cose (work fine):

```
        dlib::array<array2d<unsigned char> > images;
        std::vector<std::vector<rectangle> > object_locations, ignore;
        // Parser[0] is an input XML
        ignore = load_image_dataset(images, object_locations, parser[0]);

        // Add rotations for every training image in steps of 1 degrees from -7 to +7.
        matrix<double,15,1> angles;
        double step = 1.0 * M_PI / 180.0;
        for (int r = -7; r <= 7; ++r) angles(r) = (double) r * step;
        add_image_rotations(angles, images, object_locations, ignore);
```

How can I do that by getting also the new rectangle label?